# Column delimiter not found for the column

Tags: ssis, delimiter, flat-file

I have a flat source file with following settings.
Test Qualifier = "
Header row delimiter = |
I have a Column A which has value = This is the example of "value in the source file"

The error that i am seeing is the column delimiter for the column A is not found. I see the issue here is having double quotes in the column value. Any suggestions on how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file has to be changed.  If the text qualifier of the file is a double-quote, then the actual data cannot contain double-quotes.

You can either talk to the person who creates the file and have them use a different text delimiter, or you can write a script task that edits the file and replaces the delimiting double-quotes with another delimiter, leaving the double-quotes in the data intact.

For a bit more detail, see [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1676179-364-1.aspx).